# Is there a list on how to use material-ui icons in the svg-icons folder?

Tags: svg, material-ui

I want to use the material-ui icons in the svg-icons folder I did with npm install, but the implementations of each icon on each js file have different import like the ones in the action or in the editor etc. I had to look through the js file to find how to import each icon. I want a documentation or site that specifically lets me to copy paste the import of each icon.

I was looking for `**navigate next**` icon from google design and found it in

```js
import ImageNavigateNext from 'material-ui/svg-icons/image/navigate-next';
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Pre v1**

You can just look up the category and name on [Icons](https://design.google.com/icons/).

Every SvgIcon will map to:

```
import MyIconName from 'material-ui/svg-icons/<category>/<name>';
```

For example if I want the **account balance** icon which is part of the **action** category I would import.

```
import BalanceIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/account-balance';
```

Notice that spaces will become dashes. So the list you want is on the link above.

**v1**

With the new version of material-ui the icons are in their own package [material-ui-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-icons). Now you only have to lookup the name and **PascalCase** it to find the correct name. The category is no longer relevant. So:

```
import BalanceIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/account-balance';
```

Becomes:

```
import BalanceIcon from 'material-ui-icons/AccountBalance';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can search for the icon names in your project subdirectory `node_modules/@material-ui/icons`.

```
ls node_modules/@material-ui/icons/*.js | grep -v 'Outlined' | grep -v 'Rounded' | grep -v 'Sharp' | grep -v 'TwoTone'

node_modules/@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarms.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/Accessibility.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/AccessibilityNew.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/AccessibleForward.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/Accessible.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/AccessTime.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/AccountBalance.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/AccountBalanceWallet.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/AccountBox.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle.js
node_modules/@material-ui/icons/AcUnit.js
```

Comment: bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long

Answer (score 0):

**material-ui @v1.0.0-beta.41 is deprecated and in material-ui @v1.0.0-beta.42 It does not having svg-icons module (material-ui/svg-icons)
 So to use the module present in svg-icons in now we have t install material-ui-icons.**

> **I faced this error and after searching got to know. **

```
Module not found:Can't resolve 'material-ui/MenuItem' 

Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/svg-icons/file/file-download' 

Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/content-copy'

Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/svg-icons/toggle/star-border'

Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/delete' 

Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/svg-icons/image/remove-red-eye';
```

**Example:**

> After installing material-ui @v1.0.0-beta.42 also install
>   material-ui-icons link:

[material-ui-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-icons)

```
npm install --save material-ui-icons
```

> Few modules which are not present in material-ui @v1.0.0-beta.42 are
>   and that are present in 'material-ui-icons':

```
// import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';//this was used in version material-ui @v1.0.0-beta.41
import { MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';//Now in version material-ui @v1.0.0-beta.42, also need to install material-ui-icons

// import RemoveRedEye from 'material-ui/svg-icons/image/remove-red-eye';
import RemoveRedEye from 'material-ui-icons/RemoveRedEye';

import PersonAdd from 'material-ui-icons/PersonAdd';

// import ContentCopy from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/content-copy';
import ContentCopy from 'material-ui-icons/ContentCopy';

// import Download from 'material-ui/svg-icons/file/file-download';
import FileDownload from 'material-ui-icons/FileDownload';

// import Delete from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/delete';
import Delete from 'material-ui-icons/Delete';

// import StarBorder from 'material-ui/svg-icons/toggle/star-border';
import StarBorder from 'material-ui-icons/StarBorder';
```

Comment: material-ui-icons has been deprecated, please use @material-ui/icons instead.

Comment: you can Use @material-ui/icons instead, its deprecated for new installation but for old users its working who want to stick with that version